# Perl expect qr variable

Tags: regex, perl, ssh, expect

I'd like to know how to use variable in an expect [qr/../] command

I tried this :

```
    my $hostname = $ARGV[3];
    my $quotedhostname = quotemeta($hostname);

    $exp->spawn("ssh -o ConnectTimeout=$connectTimeout $user\@$ip") or die ("unable to spawn \n");
    @obj=$exp->expect( $commandTimeout,
        [ qr/[Pp]assword:\s*/ => sub 
        {
            print "password sent";
            my $exp = shift;
            $exp->send($passwdused, "\n");  #ecriture du mot de pass routeur
            $exp->expect($commandTimeout2,);
            exp_continue;
        }
        ],
        [ qr/.*$quotedhostname.*/ => sub
            {
            print "hostname captured"
            $exp->send("term length 0", "\n");
            $exp->expect($commandTimeout2,);
            executeCommands();
            }
        ]
    );
```

But Expect don't understand $hostname as a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function in your regex.

You can also use \Q to autoescape:  `qr/.*\Q$hostname\E.*/`

Comment: That's what i'm trying. \Q alone is not enough. I'll try with \E

Comment: I tried with \Q$hostname\E and with my $quotedhostname = quotemeta($hostname);
I added some code above, i can see the print "password sent"
but I don't see the print "hostname captured"

Comment: You have used this `my $quotedhostname = quotemeta($hostname);`. But you used `qr/.*$hostname.*/` instead of `qr/.*$quotedhostname .*/ `

Comment: Edited. It's not working either... I guess the issue is coming from somewhere else... I'm going to investigate this. Thanks for help !